# Safari Content Security Policy error on Hello World page

Tags: javascript, html, safari, content-security-policy

I have my CSP set up correctly, but I am getting a CSP error on Safari only. All other browsers are fine:

```
Report Only] Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

I get this on all my pages, so I decided to strip it right down. I now have a "hello world" page with nothing else on it. Not even html.

Safari of course adds the <html> and <body> tags on the fly so the entire page looks like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
```

I notice the network tab is empty besides the page load, and my CSP report URL.

I also however, notice that safari seems to be injecting some Extension script called `content-script.js`. Could it be this that's causing the CSP to kick in?

How is it i'm getting this CSP error on a page with literally hello world printed on it. The only thing I can see it could be is the safari injected script, and I don't know how to remove it or accept it in the CSP.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s probably a Safari extension inserting a script. Happens to me in Firefox sometimes

Comment: It is a Safari extension. Disabling extensions stops it, but we can't ask our users to disable extensions. It's not one I put on myself. Is there a way to stop the script executing from within javascript, or have the CSP allow the extension?

Comment: Extension writers need to write their extensions better. That’s about all that can be said.

Comment: Most users will never notice the error messages in Console, so the issue may be academic

Comment: That's true, I'm a little concerned about Safari users maxing out our reporting quota though. We get 10k report hits a month so every CSP violation is eating away from the quota. It's a little harder to weed out the real issues!

Comment: Can you rewrite your CSP logging routine to exclude extension errors?

Comment: Keep in mind: it's probably not just Safari users. It's only Safari for *you* because of where you have extensions installed ;-)

Comment: Right, so I checked reports-uri (which is where our logging goes to) and they had a setting to filter out extensions from the reports, but they're definitely still slipping through.

Comment: Thanks, I also do see Chrome errors although my extensions don't trigger them, other people might well do so. I think there's nothing we can do about it. Will have to just log it all, maybe pay for a bigger package if we hit our quota regularly. As long as the CSP violation won't screw up the website for the users who are getting it!

Comment: What a strange error. It is indeed an extension (LastPass, in my case) that causes the error, but the extension continues to function despite the CSP supposedly blocking it.